# Using TypeScript Enum as object property keys

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use Enum values as the keys for an object, expecting this to preserve the type when I get the value, but I'm getting `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`.

```
export enum TaskType {
  Classification = 'classification',
  Extraction = 'extraction'
}
const comparisons: { [name in TaskType]: Function } = {
  'classification': () => false,
  'extraction': () => false
}
for (const taskType in comparisons) {
  // I expect func to be of type Function, but I get a TypeScript error:
  // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type
  const func = comparisons[taskType] 
}
```

I've tried using `const func = comparisons[taskType as keyof TaskType]` but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

`taskType` in `for-in` is a string type, you cannot map it with an enum type under `comparisons`.

You can cast it to `TaskType` enum by `as` like the below code snippet instead.

*Side note, instead of using a static string key for `comparisons`, you can use enum keys directly on it.*

```
export enum TaskType {
  Classification = 'classification',
  Extraction = 'extraction'
}
const comparisons: { [name in TaskType]: Function } = {
  [TaskType.Classification]: () => false,
  [TaskType.Extraction]: () => false
}
for (const taskType in comparisons) {
  const func = comparisons[taskType as TaskType] //cast it to an enum type
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwCoEMDOBrDATzGDgG8BYAKDjgGEAbXHASwDMWBjLGFiROAF44Ack5McrDt178RAGmq0AoiBhQsnWQOEjQ6zdpHUAvtU78c8C6jBYoLHJYBc5OAG1EWVKRYDs%20EQkALquAGLIiFp8AiZC5EoeAQTEwAB0jMzsXDwxoXAAFACUQgB8cGxYDDjAijRJuCkkaaoG0fz5xWUVVTWm1GzQhRaIVnAwjUG%20AjZ2Dk6jJZT1I2NskZzxs-aOlu4TgalwuJiTqcFwpkA)